# jQuery spinner not working on ajax post

Tags: jquery

I am having issues getting my spinner to show up on the ajax post. I've tried a few different methods but I cant get it to display and then hide. If I use the showPageLoagingMsg and don't hide it after the spinner shows up but of course does not go away. I'm not opposed to any suggestions on how to get the loader to display then hide for this ajax post.

Here is my code:

```
var authorizationToken = "Basic " + userId + ":" + password;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function (request){ 
             request.setRequestHeader("AUTHORIZATION", authorizationToken);
             //$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "Loading"); -- Not working I know its deprecated but I thought I would try it any way
             $.mobile.loading('show', {theme:"a", text:"Please wait...", textonly:false, textVisible: true}); 
            },
            url: url,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
               //do stuff here
            },
            error: function (x, status, error) {
              //Do more stuff here
            },
       complete: function(){
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
                //$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        }
        });
    })
```

Any suggestions/solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping a setTimeout() around the ajax call?

Comment: That did not work either. Its strange that it will not even come up when I do that mobile.loading even if i leave the hide out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to fix this is put the call on click to show, then added a timeout to hide it. Seems to work pretty well.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       $("#refreshButton").click(function (e) {
         $.mobile.loading('show');
         RefreshDataSubmit(); //Where im doing the ajax post
         setTimeout(function(){
          $.mobile.loading('hide');
         }, 5750);
       });
    </script>
```